# how to add html file to html file without jquery

Tags: html, file, load, addition

When a div is clicked on my site, I want the contents of another html file to be added to the existing html. I've tried many methods and cannot find a solution. I don't want to use iframe or object or jquery or php.

```
function loadhtmlfile(filename, filetype, location){
      var fileref=document.createElement('link');
      fileref.setAttribute("rel", "html");
      fileref.setAttribute("type","text/html");
      fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
      document.getElementById("parentDiv").appendChild(fileref);
    }

loadhtmlfile("my.html", "html", "parentDiv");
```

This adds a link for the html file. It doesn't add the actual content of the html file.

Also from what I've read, it sounds like it may be best to do this using a server application. I'm using node.js. If it's best doing this server side, how do I do this using node.js?

Also I will be using websockets so I suspect this will change answers.

Answer (score 0):

You just could use XMLHttpRequest with javascript to load HTML content :

```
function loadFile(file) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', file);

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() { // load the page asynchronously
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) { // if the file is correctly loaded

            document.getElementById('yourelement').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; 

        }

    });

    xhr.send(null); 

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a version of this with web sockets? I'm using websockets not https

Comment: Not from me, I'm not familiar with websockets. However I had to use it once, I got my code inspired from this one, hope it can help you : https://github.com/zhenbianshu/websocket